# Boolean Contour of Array Elements

Tags: python, numpy, boolean

I have the following array

```
array = np.array(\
       [[  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255],
       [   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255, 255, 255],
       [   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
       [   0,   0,   0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
       [   0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255]])
```

I would like to get a boolean array where the value is True whenever the element above and next is different (or if it's on the edge of the array):

```
[[ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True False]
 [ True False False False False  True  True False False False]
 [ True False False  True  True False False False False False]
 [ True True  True False False False False False False False]
 [ True False False False False False False False False False]]
```

*What I have tried so far:*
I look for every row if the next neighbor is different:

```
row = np.array([np.append(row[:-1] != row[1:],False) for row in mapped_image])
```

For every column:

```
column = []
rowAbove = mapped_image[0]
for row in mapped_image[1:]:
    column .append(rowAbove != row)
    rowAbove = row
column .append(["True"]*len(row))
```

... but then I have difficulties merging them together and adding the edge. What can I try to solve this?

Comment: Wrt _"the value is True whenever the element above and next is different"_ - from each other or different from the element? In the last row of the result the first value has `True` when the value above it is 0 and next to it (right side) is 255. And then the third element on the last row is `False` but also has 0 above it and 255 after. They should both be either True or False. And the original value in those position are 0 and 255. So again, they should have the same result. Btw, the top row and right-most column show be _all_ True. Why is the top-right corner and right-most column all False?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want to mask consecutive elements where the difference is non zero (except for edges). You could take a look at [`np.diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html#numpy-diff) for this:

```
diff_y = np.diff(array, append=255, axis=-2)
# True if it's on the edge of the array
diff_y[:,0] = 255
diff_y[0,:] = 255

print(diff_y != 0)
```

Output:

```
[[ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True False False False False  True  True False False False]
 [ True False False  True  True False False False False False]
 [ True  True  True False False False False False False False]
 [ True False False False False False False False False False]]
```

This is not the exact output you wanted, but this might give you some idea.

Comment: Hi Kevin, Thanks a lot for your answer! Actually, what do you think about augmenting the original array by adding an artificial border of with 255 all around the array, then doing the np.diff() and "cutting" out the useful boolean part. What do you think about this approach?

Comment: Hi, I think it might work. ```np.pad(array, [1,1], constant_values=255)``` will create the artificial boarder.